# How to add markers to a wave file, so that if that wave file is played (with other sounds), one can find that marker in the output stream

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio, waveform

I want to add markers to a few wave files. When they are played by my computer together with some music in the backround I would like to be able to programmatically find those markers.

I thought about using NAudio and process the data whenever sound is played. Thisis how I initialize it:

```
    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var deviceToRecord = (new MMDeviceEnumerator().EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active))[0];

        var recorder = new CustomWasapiLoopbackCapture(deviceToRecord, false, 1000);
        recorder.ShareMode = AudioClientShareMode.Shared;
        recorder.DataAvailable += recorderDataAvailable;

        var inprov = new WaveInProvider(recorder);
        var fto16prov = new WaveFloatTo16Provider(inprov);
        var stomprov = new StereoToMonoProvider16(fto16prov);

        recorder.StartRecording();
    }


    static void recorderDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs args)
    {
        // Here I get the bytes in args.BytesRecorded whenever the sound is playing
    }
```

Each 2 bytes in a wave file are a number in little-endian notation (from -32'767 to 32'767). I could distort the sound a little by introducing a pattern that would be unique. But the question is - will I be able to find those bytes in the output stream? Unfortunately the bytes in the output stream are totally different from bytes in the wave file even if that's the only sound the computer made.

Answer (score 0):

The [cues chunk](https://www.recordingblogs.com/wiki/cue-chunk-of-a-Wave-file) could perhaps be used for this. NAudio includes some basic support for cues with `CueWaveFileReader` and `CueWaveFileWriter`